# Javascript files getting corrupted automatically

Tags: javascript, browser, corruption

A strange thing happening to my system, 
My JavaScript files are getting corrupted automatically. like this:

```
�������������������������������������
```

I have never touched the file which are getting corrupted.

if I replace corrupted file with backup then again any other file get corrupted, This strange thing is happening in my whole localhost. I am sure it is not happaning due to any virus, I have tested my whole localhost files by many antivirus.

Is browser is doing this ?, cause which files are corrupting, they are only accessed by browser.

please help me.

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of the JS files?

Comment: I use wordpress, core wordpress JS are getting corrupted

Comment: If it's on a production site, and this suddenly happened, you have a problem

Comment: In my locallhost, This is happening from past 1 month, only JavaScript files are corrupting

Answer (score 0):

Often these issues can be due to encoding. If your JS files are saved in a different encoding than your web browser is expecting, then you see the strange question marks.

Joel has a great post about encoding on his blog and although it's kind of long I do suggest you read it to get a better understanding of encoding and how it works, if you are not already familiar with it.

By the way, UTF-8 is the most popular encoding on the internet for a reason! Check it out.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: File are totally corrupted not even open in Notepad++, notepad show `NULL NULL NULL`