# Browser loads corrupted old Javascript

Tags: javascript

A Javascript file which I'm currently frequently changing, gets loaded corrupted by the browser (Chrome, Firefox). First of all, the actual file loaded is an old one and not the currently saved one. Second, the file frequently seems to be either just partly loaded (e.g. the last few characters don't appear) or I get a `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error message.

During development, I'm disabling caching, so that's not the reason for the 'old' javascript version. Also, 'Empty Cache and Hard reload' on Chrome doesn't change anything either.

After looking at [Javascript files getting corrupted automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772910/javascript-files-getting-corrupted-automatically), I've ensured the file is UTF-8 encoded.

Any help, tip would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Open source code in web browser, check link to javascript file and ensure that it is pointing to updated code.

Comment: @niyasc: The javascript is definitely pointing to the updated code. Sometimes just shutting down the server and restarting it half an hour later magically seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure about the client side not doing any caching then what remains are the server side and whatever is between:

- Is there a proxy? Those pieces of software can sometime create big problems because of their interpretation of caching policies or just because of bugs.
- What is the server serving the files? How is the script updated on the server? Often you can run into problems if the server clock and the client uploading the file are not perfectly synchronized because a server-side caching may think the file didn't actually change. Problems may happen if when uploading the file you're also uploading metadata like modification datetime instead of having the server setting the modification time equal to the upload time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The only meta data I have is `charset="UTF-8"` and it's all running on localhost (no proxy).